# How to properly pass u8 string literal to C function accepting UTF-8 string

Tags: c++, interop, c++20

How can the new `char8_t` be used together with a C interface?

```
extern "C"
    {
    struct PangoLayout;
    void pango_layout_set_text(PangoLayout* layout, char const* text, int length);
    }

#include <string_view>

void printText(PangoLayout* layout, std::u8string_view str)
    {
    // Does not compile:
    // pango_layout_set_text(layout, static_cast<char const*>(str.data()), std::size(str));

    // Does not compile:
    // pango_layout_set_text(layout, static_cast<char const*>(str.data()), std::size(str));

    // UB?:
    pango_layout_set_text(layout, reinterpret_cast<char const*>(str.data()), std::size(str));
    }

void hello(PangoLayout* layout)
    {
    printText(layout, u8"Hello@ł€ð®þ$đßđ®");
    }
```

Is better to continue use char in this case? This avoids `reinterpret_cast` but also reduces expressiveness.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What is *wrong* with the `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: @NicolBolas Type-punned pointer

Comment: But it's 100% legal. And you're interop-ing with a language that doesn't have `char8_t` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the `char8_t` [P0482](http://wg21.link/p0482) proposal.

[P1423](http://wg21.link/p1423) documents a number of approaches and techniques intended to help address the backward compatibility issues resulting from the adoption of P0482.

Using `reinterpret_cast` is a viable (if distasteful) option.  Note that, because `char8_t` is *not* an aliasing type, `reinterpret_cast` cannot be used to acquire a `char8_t` based pointer to `char` or `unsigned char` based data, but use of `reinterpret_cast` in the other direction is ok (because `char` and `unsigned char` are already allowed to alias all types; see [[basic.lval]p11](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#basic.lval-11)).

An option to avoid sprinkling `reinterpret_cast` all over the code base would be to provide overloads that wrap the `char` based interfaces.  For example:

```
inline void pango_layout_set_text(PangoLayout* layout, char8_t const* text, int length) {
  return pango_layout_set_text(layout, reinterpret_cast<char const*>(text), length);
}
```